# AngularStrap timepicker format

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using AngularTrap timepicker, and problem is I can not find a way how to make 24 hours time format.

```
   <div class="control-group input-append">
          <input class="input-small" data-minute-step="5" data-modal-backdrop="true" type="text" ng-model="timepicker.time" bs-timepicker>
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="timepicker"><i class="icon-time"></i></button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution right after posting question: just add `"data-show-meridian="false""`

```
<div class="control-group input-append">
    <input class="input-small" data-minute-step="5" data-show-meridian="false" data-modal-backdrop="true" type="text" ng-model="timepicker.time" bs-timepicker>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="timepicker"><i class="icon-time"></i></button>
</div>
```

All list of parameters: http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You should add this attribute to time picker element :

```
data-time-format="HH:mm:ss"
```